# How to switch activity after catching an exception in android?

Tags: java, android, try-catch

The code below has caught an exception. Now i want to switch to my MainActivity from the current activity just after the Toast message has been displayed. Is it possible ? if yes how?

```
catch(JSONException e){
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Word is not availabe" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. Just use the same code you would use to start a new Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value used for `Toast.LENGTH_LONG` is `3500` ms. So, if you want to start your `Activity` after the `Toast` is shown, you could post a delayed `Runnable` for a slightly longer duration, like `4000` ms.

Here's an example:

```
    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Word is not availabe",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();
    toast.getView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourNewActivity.class));
        }
    }, 4000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start a new activity,

Use `Intent`

Return to root/previous activity call `onBackPressed();`